# multiple eager loading with include in sequelizeJs

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have multiple Models **Partners**, **PartnerUsers**, **ContentRequest** and **UserContents**.

Association is like

```
// Association between Partner & PartnerUsers
m.Partners.hasMany(m.PartnerUsers);
m.PartnerUsers.belongsTo(m.Partners);

// Association between PartnerUsers & UserContents
m.PartnerUsers.hasMany(m.UserContents);
m.UserContents.belongsTo(m.PartnerUsers);

// Association between Partner & ContentRequests
m.Partners.hasMany(m.ContentRequests);
m.ContentRequests.belongsTo(m.Partners);
```

Now I am using eager loading and I don't know how to use multiple eager loading.
I am doing like this

```
Partner.find(
  where: {
    id: id
  },
  include: [PartnerContents, ContentRequests],
  include: [{
    model: PartnerUsers,
    include: [UserContents]
    }]
  )
  .success(function(partner){ 
  })
```

But not giving me **partner.partnerContents & partner.contentRequests**

I'am having **patner.partnerUsers[0].userContents **

If I did it like this

```
Partner.find(
  where: {
    id: id
  },
  include: [PartnerContents]
  //include: [{
  //  model: PartnerUsers,
  //  include: [UserContents]
  //  }]
  )
  .success(function(partner){ 
  })
```

I'am having **patner.partnerContents**

Suggest me how can I get all three by association like **patner.partnerContents , patner.contentRequests and patner.partnerUsers[0].userContents**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

see [documentation](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/wiki/API-Reference-Model#params-3) options.include

check this:

```
Partner.find({
    where: {
        id: id
    },
    include: [
        PartnerContents,
        ContentRequests,
        {
            model: PartnerUsers,
            include: [UserContents]
        }
    ]})
    .success(function(partner) {

    });
```